# Equating multiple new variables with an old one

Tags: coding-style, readability

Sometimes I run into a situation where I need to equate two new variables with an old one. Which of the following (if any) is a good practice (w.r.t. code readability or any other factor), under what conditions?

```
a=b;
c=b;
```

or

```
a=b;
c=a;
```

Note, `a`,`b` and `c` are just the names chosen in this example.

Comment: Which shows the intent?  Are `a` and `c` both to be equal to `b`? or is `c` supposed to be equal to `a`?

Comment: @MichaelT Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by intent. Underlying values need to be equal.

Comment: "a and c are equal to b" vs "a gets the value of b, and c is a loop index that is initialized to a."  These are different statements that have different implications on the code that is written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Humans are Parsers Too! Encourage Maximum Readability!

Given your 2 choices, **I'd favor the first one**:

```
a = b;
c = b;
```

It's easier to visually parse and to figure out that both `a` and `c` now have the same value as `b`. Or at least you quickly see that 2 separate things get the same value.

In the second example, none of this is immediately obvious.

### Discourage Ambiguity

I'd also discourage one-liners (`a = b = c;`) for similar reasons, and because they hide multiple expressions in a single statement. This facilitates the introduction of fly-by errors<sup>*</sup> and leads to developing a (bad) habit of cramming too much in too little space for a false sense of expressiveness.

---

<sup>*</sup> For instance, I've often come across things like:

- `a = b = b;` (when obviously a `c` was intended somewhere),
- and then quickly you'll see things like `if (a == (b = c)) {}`... and now you're one typo away from `if (a = (b = c))` and then you've got absolutely no clue what the intended behavior was. Ah, and use descriptive variable names, obviously.

Comment: I guess it is a moot question as to when code stops being terse and starts becoming unreadable. Ternary operators seem to be a particular bone of contention in our office e.g. result = a > b ? x : y;

Comment: @RobbieDee: ternaries are fine as long as you don't abuse them: you just use them to return an expression's result based on a condition (but not to branch entire sections of code), and you don't nest them unreasonably just for the sake of saving some lines (though formatted correctly, thay may be decently readable, it's likely you can re-design your logic differently).

Answer (score 3):

If the language allows for this syntax (and most do), I'd highly prefer this:

```
a = c = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to agree with deceze. Yes, this example is clear(ish):

```
a = b; 
c = b;
```

But introduce more variables and it just becomes horrible:

```
a = z;

b = z;

c = z;

.

.

.

w = z;

x = z;

y = z;
```

At which point would you draw the line and go for the single assignment statement? 3 variables? 4? 5?

Setting some arbitrary limit would seem to be daft (and in contravention of the [Zero One Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule)).

Comment: one would hope that as you introduce more variables you eventually use some sort of collection instead

Comment: @Robbie: I think that if you start to introduce variables this way,  your problem lies somewhere else... Either in your overall design, or in the fact that you don't separate that into smaller chunks and functions anyways.

Comment: Yes, the extreme example was designed to demonstrate that if it doesn't scale for more elements, the approach shouldn't be used at all - hence why I upvoted @jk.

Comment: @RobbieDee: using lots of `if() {}` statements doesn't scale either. Doesn't mean you should avoid them at all costs.

Comment: We're in danger of speculating about designs on imaginary code so I'm going to side-step that one as off-topic... :)